# Why recursive function in decorator calls its inner function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, closures, decorator

why recursive `func(n)` at line 4 calls `inner` function n times, not only original function `fact`.

```
def log(func):
    def inner(n):
        print('inner()')
        result = func(n)
        return result
    return inner

def fact(n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else n*fact(n-1)

fact = log(fact)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fact(4)
```

Output what confused me (expected print to run only once):

```
inner()
inner()
inner()
inner()
```

In line `fact = log(fact)` decorator `log` returns reference to `inner` function object. This reference is assigned to name `fact` and `fact.__name__` now prints `inner`. Also, when I check `id(fact)` it returns new value.

Inside decorated `fact` function free variable `func` still points to original `fact` function object. I can make sure of it by using `id(func)` or `func.__name__` inside `inner`, it is same as before decorate. And the part I just don't get it. When recursive function runs in line `result = func(n)` inside `inner`, `func(n)` calls decorated `fact`(or `inner`) not original `fact`. It confuses me, because `func` still points to original `fact`.

Why recursive function inside decorator calls its inner function, not original function, which was passed to decorator and still have reference to it?

Comment: `inner` replaces `fact`. Any recursive call to `fact` is a call to `inner`.

Comment: It actually calls both, but `fact` is called inside an `inner` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood already explained `inner()` gets printed 4 times because the recursion calls the `inner` function 4 times, easy.

Your `fact` function gets called in this line `result = func(n)` **inside** the `inner` function. If you `print(fact.__name__)` the output is `inner`, because `fact` **is** the `inner` function.

This may get confusing, because every function you pass inside your `log` decorator will become an `inner` function.
To avoid this confusion, I suggest to use the `wraps` decorator like this:

```
from functools import wraps
def log(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(n):
        print('inner()')
        result = func(n)
        return result
    return inner
```

This way, the `func` you pass inside your decorator will maintain the original identity, and `print(fact.__name__)` will print `fact`.

Comment: If i do `func.__name__`, or `id(func)` inside `inner`, it prints `fact` and still has reference to original function. Why then `func(n)` calls `inner`?

Comment: Because `fact` is both the name of your function and the variable. You should't do this because it's confusing. When you write `fact` it references to the variable, not the function, and since the value of the variable `fact` is `log(fact)` the `log` function gets called and return `inner`. So change the name of your variable with something like  `logging_fact` and it will be clearer.

Comment: @edzoons Basically what your `log()` does is returning a `inner` func, any variable you assign to `log()` will be an inner function. You overwrite the `fact` name and that shouldn't be done.

Comment: Oh. It finally clicked with me, what you both (@JLeno46 and @khelwood ) were trying to say me. The original `fact` function loads global name `fact`, which by the way is the decorated `fact`. Thanks.

Comment: @khelwood if I change the name `fact` to `logging_fact`, the function isin't decorated any more. Still, it helped me to understand it.

Comment: @edzoons you can use `logging_fact` as the decorated version of your function `fact` and calling `logging_fact(4)` will give you the same output.

Comment: @khelwood actually no. Returned result may be the same, but different things behind the sceen happen. If i do `log_fact = log(fact)` and then `log_fact(4)`,  `inner` is caled only once and the `print('inner()')` will output only once. When using `fact=log(fact)`, 'inner()'  is print out 4 times.

Comment: @edzoons You're right, my bad. As you probably already understood, that's because only the first call is the decorated  `fact ` and the 3 recursive calls are non-decorated `fact`, since the `fact` name is no longer overwritten. Talking about confusion relative to closures and recursion :)